# Error with mongodb. Missing "}" after property list

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, bson

with the following code I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list <shell>:3
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? The curly braces seem balanced so I am wondering if I made a mistake somewhere else.

```
db.test.save(
{
     "name":"John Doe"
     "attribute":"false"
     "num1":99
     "num2":85
     "num3"{
            "n1":11
            "n2":9
            "n3":8
            "n4":9
     }
     "num4"{
            "m1":15
            "m2":6
            "m3":5
            "m4":12
     }
}
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing colons.

```
 "num3":{
       ^

 "num4":{
       ^
```

And also commas.

```
 "name":"John Doe",
                  ^
 "attribute":"false",
                    ^
 "num3"{
        "n1":11, //commas to separate these object properties too
        "n2":9,
        "n3":8,
        "n4":9
 },
  ^
 //etc
```

This should execute:

```
{
     "name":"John Doe",
     "attribute":"false",
     "num1":99,
     "num2":85,
     "num3":{
            "n1":11,
            "n2":9,
            "n3":8,
            "n4":9
     },
     "num4":{
            "m1":15,
            "m2":6,
            "m3":5,
            "m4":12
     }
}
```

There are also some examples of valid `document`s in the [MongoDB update docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/).

Comment: No problem, this syntax is very similar (if not identical) to JS object literals that you often use in both Node and front-end JS development.

Comment: Yeah I have never used JS, and I need to write some JS that performs operations to calculate numbers based on the attribute value and the numbers in the lists, so hopefully I can figure that out. I might end up back on stack overflow in an hour

Either way, thanks again!